# Counting Sort Algorithm in C++ minor mistake

Tags: c++, algorithm

I followed counting algorithm and implemented it in C++ but the output is not as per requirement.
It should output 35 60 81 98.

**Counting Algorithm**

```
1.  for  i=0 to n-1 do
2.       count[i] = 0
3.  end for
4.  for i =0 to n-2 do
5.       for j = i+1 to n-1 do
6.        if A[i] < A[j]
7.          count[j] = count[j] +1
8.        else count[i] = count[i] +1
9.  end if
10. end for
11. end for
12. for I = 0 to n-1
13.    S[count[i]] = A[i]
14. End for
15. Return S
```

**Implemented Code**

```
int main(){ 
    int A[4] = {60, 35, 81, 98};   
    int count[4], S[5];
    int i, n=4, j;

    system("cls");
    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
             count[i] = 0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<n-2; i++){
             for(j=i+1; j<n-1; j++){
                        if(A[i] < A[j]){
                              count[j] = count[j] + 1;
                        }else{
                              count[i] = count[i] + 1;
                        }
             }
    }

    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
             S[count[i]] = A[i];             
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
             cout << S[i] << endl;
    }


    getchar();
}
```

**Output**

35

60

81

1976672506

Where did I go wrong? The Last number is not correct. Please help!

Comment: looks like you are losing the last entry, which is getting replaced by a garbage value!

Comment: @binaryBaBa yeah, that's right. Any suggestions?

Comment: `0 to n-1` is an inclusive range. In C you use semi-open ranges so the condition becomes `i < n` ("up to but not including n"), not `i < n-1`.

Comment: @n.m.thanks a lot bro, your solution worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had mistake in for section. Then I edited your code and edited version in bellow:

```
for (i = 0; i<n; i++){
    count[i] = 0;
}
//if i<n in bellow for no problem occure

for (i = 0; i<n -1; i++){
    for (j = i + 1; j<n; j++){
        if (A[i] < A[j]){
            count[j] = count[j] + 1;
        }
        else{
            count[i] = count[i] + 1;
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i<n ; i++){
    S[count[i]] = A[i];
}

for (i = 0; i<n; i++){
    cout << S[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
             for(j=i+1; j<n; j++){
                        if(A[i] < A[j]){
                              count[j] = count[j] + 1;
                        }else{
                              count[i] = count[i] + 1;
                        }
             }
    }
```

This is what you should use!

Notice that I am running both the loops one more time (to also consider the last element of the array which was otherwise lost!)

Also, while filling the sorted array:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
             S[count[i]] = A[i];             
    }
```